# chrubuntu 12.04 lts stopped working need help?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, google-chrome, chromebook

I installed a new kernel version for Ubuntu and rebooted it stopped working, And then i tried going to chrome OS and back to Ubuntu and it just gives me a full screen command prompt that just allows me to type, As far as i know the kernel may be corrupt and i need help getting it back, please been battling it for like a  day now, what can i do to fix the corrupt kernel?

Comment: You have mentioned "Chrubuntu" - is your system actually running Ubuntu at all?

Comment: Yes its is running a modified variant of Ubuntu made for chromebooks

Answer (score 0):

Chrubuntu uses a special kernel since it is having to run on top of ChromeOS which has a custom ChromeOS Linux kernel. The newer Chromebooks don't have this problem and can use a PC bios which makes it easier to use a standard Linux kernel. Here are a few more details on why this is so...

http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.mx/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html